# AVFoundation Focus Mode iPad2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, avfoundation, autofocus

I am trying to make auto focus work in my app, tested in iPad2. My problem is that when I called check methods like `isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus`, it always return NO. However, I could tap to focus with other camera applications in my device

```
devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *tempDevice in devices) {
    [tempDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if ([tempDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {
        NSLog(@"Here");
    }

    if ([tempDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus]) {
        NSLog(@"Here");
    }

    if ([tempDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked]) {
        NSLog(@"Here");
    }

    if ([tempDevice isFocusPointOfInterestSupported]) {
        NSLog(@"Here");
    }
    [tempDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was just looking into this tonight. From what I have gleaned, the iPad 2 doesn't do *focus* - it does *exposure adjustment* - so in the default Camera app, tapping the screen brings up a rect where the tap occurred indicating the area to do *white point adjustment* on.

Perhaps I am wrong but this is what I have turned up, and seems to be confirmed by your API (`isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus` returning NO) tests.

The cameras in the iPad 2 are pretty weak - especially the front-facing one. I am surprised Apple shipped with that.

**UPDATE:** This is the code from the more recent AVCamDemo Apple sample that handles focus + exposure + white point. I don't think this is in the AVCam example. AVCamDemo may onlly be available as a download of the WWDC code .dmg package from the developer center - not as a single download from the web.
 On my iPad 2 the exposure code never gets called.
//-from AVCamDemo:

```
- (BOOL) hasExposure
 {
AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];

return  [device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked] ||
        [device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose] ||
        [device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];
}

- (AVCaptureExposureMode) exposureMode
{
return [[[self videoInput] device] exposureMode];
}

- (void) setExposureMode:(AVCaptureExposureMode)exposureMode
{
if (exposureMode == 1) {
    exposureMode = 2;
}
AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];
if ([device isExposureModeSupported:exposureMode] && [device exposureMode] != exposureMode) {
    NSError *error;
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        [device setExposureMode:exposureMode];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    } else {
        id delegate = [self delegate];
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:)]) {
            [delegate acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:error];
        }
    }
}
}

- (BOOL) hasWhiteBalance
{
AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];

return  [device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked] ||
        [device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeAutoWhiteBalance];
}

- (AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode) whiteBalanceMode
{
return [[[self videoInput] device] whiteBalanceMode];
}

- (void) setWhiteBalanceMode:(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode)whiteBalanceMode
{
if (whiteBalanceMode == 1) {
    whiteBalanceMode = 2;
}    
AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];
if ([device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:whiteBalanceMode] && [device whiteBalanceMode] != whiteBalanceMode) {
    NSError *error;
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        [device setWhiteBalanceMode:whiteBalanceMode];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    } else {
        id delegate = [self delegate];
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:)]) {
            [delegate acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:error];
        }
    }
}
}

- (BOOL) hasFocus
{
AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];

return  [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked] ||
        [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus] ||
        [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
}

- (AVCaptureFocusMode) focusMode
{
return [[[self videoInput] device] focusMode];
}

- (void) setFocusMode:(AVCaptureFocusMode)focusMode
{


AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];
if ([device isFocusModeSupported:focusMode] && [device focusMode] != focusMode) {
    NSError *error;

      printf(" setFocusMode    \n");
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        [device setFocusMode:focusMode];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    } else {
        id delegate = [self delegate];
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:)]) {
            [delegate acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:error];
        }
    }    
}
}
```

Comment: so, how does the app show the white rectangle and there is some effects changing

Comment: Take a look at the AVCam example (there is another, I think more recent `AVCamDemo` around too): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112

Comment: I'm working with the AVCam example at the moment to craft my own custom interface.  It contain code that tests for isFocusPointOfInterestSupported.        
My iPad 2 definitely skips this.  I trust the 'new' iPad makes use of it.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code from the AVCamDemo. Focus never gets called on my iPad 2. ...strange but true... ;-)

Comment: Hello, any idea how iPad 2 camera app sets the white balance on tapping the screen? There's setWhiteBalanceMode: method, but I can't see anything like setWhiteBalancePointOfInterest

Comment: Apparently iPad 2 does not support Auto focus/expose/whitebalance mode; it does support ContinuousAuto and Locked focus/expose/whitebalance modes. Setting focus point of interest is not supported, exposure point of interest is supported. Any suggestion how with these settings could be achieved default iOS tap-to-adjust camera behaviour? Thanks